# Gradle wait for ANT task to complete

Tags: ant, gradle

I have a gradle task that calls ant.exec() to do svn export into a directory:

```
/*
 *  Get code from repository into the 'src' directory
 */
task getSource << {
    ant.exec(executable: svn_executable) {
      arg(value: 'export')
      arg(value: repository)
      arg(value: 'src')
   }
}
```

Then I have a task that deletes certain files in the exported directory:

```
task deletes(type: Delete) {
    ant.delete() {
        fileset(dir: "src", includes: "**/*template*")
    }
}
```

And then I have another task that calls **getSource** and **deletes** one after another.

The problem is that gradle doesn't wait for the **getSource** to complete and goes straight ahead to the next task, which is a problem, since at that moment there are no files that need to be deleted.

Is there a way to get around this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'deletes' task calls ant.delete in the configuration phase instead of the execution phase of gradle. Have a look on the Gradle DSL reference about how to configure the 'Delete' task correctly at http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Delete.html

hope that helps,

cheers,

René

Answer (score 1):

> And then I have another task that calls getSource and deletes one after another.

What exactly do you mean by this? A Gradle task cannot call other tasks; it can only depend on them.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The other task depends on *getSource* and *deletes*